# Add a custom CSS class to a popup triggered by kendoEditor's toolbar actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendo-editor

I'd like to add a custom CSS class to a popup opened via kendoEditor's toolbar (for example "Insert Hyperlink").

I've tried looking at the kendoEditor's instance object (`$("#Comments").kendoEditor().data('kendoEditor')`) but I could only find stuff related to the widget itself, not the additional element it opens / fires (such as the popups).

I've also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08qd6jdt/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to add additional classes to objects.
If you can find the class you want to edit (look in the inspecter) and call a javascript function with the jquery to change classes, you should be fine?

Let me know if you would need any more help.